# How to assign a default value to a function as parameter in Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin, default

In my Kotlin project I would like to assign a default value to a function passed as a parameter, something like:

```
fun myFun(book: String, isCool: (book: String) -> Boolean = _ -> true) {
    if (isCool(book)) println("$book is cool!")
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Unlike some other languages, in Kotlin the braces `{}` are the (only) required bit of syntax for writing a lambda. (You can omit the `->` if there are no parameters, or if there's one parameter and its type can be inferred.) So in this case it could just be `= { true }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible

```
fun myFun(book: String, isCool: (book: String) -> Boolean = { _ -> true }) {
    if (isCool(book)) println("$book is cool!")
}
```